# Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array Embers js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, ember.js, handlebars.js

here  my code .

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
        <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
        {{outlet}}
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">      
            {{#each  model1}}
            <li>title</li>
            {{/each}}       
    </script>
```

and my arraycontroller

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

});

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    model1: function () {
        return posts;
    } 

});
```

And My Json

```
posts = [{
        title: "Raja",
        body: "There are lots of à la carte software environments in this world." }, {
        title: "Broken Promises",
        body: "James Coglan wrote a lengthy article about Promises in node.js." }];
```

Please tell me If it's possible to call model1 from controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it'd need to be a property, not a function

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    model1: function () {
        return posts;
    }.property()
});
```

But if it's a model it'd make more sense to return that from the route, and use the model in the controller

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return posts;
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">   
        <ul>   
        {{#each item in controller}}
          <li>{{item.title}}</li>
        {{/each}}       
        </ul>
</script>
```

Comment: please tell me How to Use observes() and Property() same function in Embers js